# How to run an Apple tvOS or IOS app, on an external Touchscreen Monitor

Tags: ios, tvos, touchscreen

It looks like Apple developers are not able to develop an app that is presented on an external TOUCHSCREEN monitor. Strange but true? Is there any way around this?
See this similar question answered by Apple: 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7421057?start=0&tstart=0

(In my case, Touchscreen touches must be handled by the app.)

Comment: Develop an iOS app and scale it up? tvOS doesn't use touch events.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Daniel,  how could I scale it up to display on and receive responses from an external Touchscreen?

Comment: That would highly depend on how your external touch screen sends touch events.

Comment: @RobvandenBerg did you get anywhere with this? I'd like to make a touchscreen app for an Apple TV, too...

Comment: @Skoop No, I dropped it. Let us know if you find a solution.....

Answer (score 0):

I've found 3 "solutions".

None ideal.

Firstly, a device is required to convert Touchscreen information into useful, formatted info that can be sent to the Apple TV. This can be something like a Raspberry PI type of thing.

Then the Apple TV needs to receive it, and your app needs to find a way to interpret this as the input it's going to focus on.

With the obvious out of the way, the three ways to handle the touch info sending:

1. Bluetooth LE transmission and reception by the AppleTV. There's no CoreMIDI BtLE access on Apple TV, so must be custom, internal to the app. Paring, etc.
2. Ethernet, RJ-45... from one "server" to another... this kills the wireless connectivity of the AppleTV, with custom handling code that's then passing this into your app.
3. Wireless information sent in this server pretence manner, and then interpreted by the app. Probably the best of the 3 ways.